# How do I go up one directory in Nautilus 43?

Tags: nautilus, directory, 22.10

I'm really struggling with some of the latest changes to Nautilus' interface.

How do I get to the directory that is the parent of the current directory if the path name is too long? I can't find any way of scrolling or dragging the directory list:

[image: Nautilus window with a bar showing parent directories]

The parent directory in the screenshot is **not** `@ST...`, I'm like 5 levels deep below that. I've found a workaround, but it's like 4 clicks just to get to a parent directory.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thank you! That keyboard shortcut does work. I'm still hoping there is a way to scroll the directory list in the GUI without needing to switch to a keyboard, but you are welcome to add that as a proper answer and I'll upvote it, because it's still very useful for anyone Googling the same question.

Comment: Nautilus developers should be tarred and feathered for not providing a simple `△` button to navigate to an upper level from the current directory. AFAIK previous versions of Nautilus did contain such a button.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key will go up one directory.